# Como poner un codigo qr en jasperreport?

Tags: jasper-reports

Estoy haciendo un reporte en el que quiero que me muestre un código qr, pero cuando pongo el código en la expresión:

Este código lo pongo en la expresión de la imagen en jasper:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.getInstance(new SimpleJasperReportsContext()).loadAwtImageFromBytes(Base64.getDecoder().decode($F{QR}))
```

El error que genera el siguiente:

> com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.errorhandler.ProblemItem@7cc43d06 Base64 cannot be resolved   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignExpression@6f24d97f

Alguien sabe como lo puedo resolver?